# R markdown: report values from dataframe as text

Tags: r, r-markdown, report, inline

Using modified mtcars dataset I try to get this output after knitting a Rmd file to html:

"The database consists of 5 car models (Mazda RX4 (mpg=21.0), Mazda RX4 Wag (mpg=21.0), Datsun 710 (mpg=22.8), Hornet 4 Drive (mpg=21.4), and Hornet Sportabout (mpg=18.7)."

What I achieved so far:

"The database consists of 5 car models (Mazda RX4, Mazda RX4 Wag, Datsun 710, Hornet 4 Drive, and Hornet Sportabout)."

Is there a way to put each mpg of the dataframe to the model of car inline? Thank you!

my Rmd file:

YAML

```
---
title: "test"
author: "TJ"
date: "27 12 2020"
output: html_document
---
```

chunk1

```
{r setup, include = TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
```

chunk 2

```
{r cars}
df <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car=rownames(mtcars),
         id = row_number()
         ) %>% 
  filter(id <= 5) %>% 
  select(car, mpg)

# count of cars
n_cars <- length(df)

# mpg of cars
mpg_cars <- df$car %>% 
  glue_collapse(sep = ", ", last = ", and ")
```

inline

```
The database consists of `r nrow(df)` car models (`r mpg_cars`).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for deleting so many times , i was working to get the best code
Here is the code

```
datasets::mtcars
cars<-mtcars
cars$make<- row.names(cars)
cars$mpg_1<-as.character(cars$mpg)
cars$x=paste(cars$make,cars$mpg_1,sep = ",")
View(cars)
```

[image]

Comment: I hope that is what you were asking , if not try giving some examples.

Comment: thank you so much Rishabh. Your first solution gave me the idea, which I was not able to think about, although now its clear for me: just save the desired output in a column (as you showed) and than glue_collapse it.

Comment: You welcome , you can try the new one as its more simple to use